# Why JsonParser gives double quotes in the return value, using com.google.gson API

Tags: java, json, gson, jsonparser, google-json-api

I am currently using JsonObject and JsonParser of com.google.gson api (using gson-2.8.5 version) to parse and read the value form input JSON.

I have JSON filed like , smaple `"resultCode":"SUCCESS",` when I try to read the same value from json it gives the  result as `""SUCCESS""` .

Every value I am reading, getting with double "" not sure why ? You can refer below screen of my debugging screen.

I am new to Json and parser, is that default behavior ?

I am expecting `"SUCCESS"`, `"S"`, `"00000000"` not like `""SUCCESS""` or `""S""`
 or `""00000000""` 
same I have highlighted in the below image .

Please share any idea how we can get apbsolute vlaue of string without """" double quote string it causing my string comparison fail.

[image]

```
String response_result = "{\"response\": {\"head\": {\"function\": \"acquiring.order.create\",\"version\": \"2.0\",\"clientId\": \"201810300000\",\"reqMsgId\": \"56805892035\",\"respTime\": \"2019-09-13T13:18:08+08:00\"},\"body\": {\"resultInfo\": {\"resultCode\": \"SUCCESS\",\"resultCodeId\": \"00000000\",\"resultStatus\": S,\"resultMsg\": \"SUCCESS\"},\"acquirementId\": \"2018080834569894848930\",\"merchantTransId\": \"5683668701112717398\",\"checkoutUrl\": \"http://localhost:8081/crm/operator/operator-search-init.action\"}},\"signature\":\"d+TUYLvt1a491R1e6aO8i9VwXWzVhfNgnhD0Du74f4RgBQ==\"}";
        HttpInvoker.Result result = i.new Result(200, response_result);
    JsonObject jo =  new JsonParser().parse(response_result).getAsJsonObject();

    String resultCode = jo.get("response").getAsJsonObject().get("body").getAsJsonObject().get("resultInfo").getAsJsonObject().get("resultCode").toString();
    String resultCodeId = jo.get("response").getAsJsonObject().get("body").getAsJsonObject().get("resultInfo").getAsJsonObject().get("resultCodeId").toString();
    String resultStatus = jo.get("response").getAsJsonObject().get("body").getAsJsonObject().get("resultInfo").getAsJsonObject().get("resultStatus").toString();
    String checkoutUrl = jo.get("response").getAsJsonObject().get("body").getAsJsonObject().get("checkoutUrl").toString();

    if ( RESULT_CODE_GCASH_SUCCESS.equals(resultCode)
            && RESULT_STATUS_SUCCESS.equals(resultStatus)
            && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(checkoutUrl)) {

        log.error("Testing ".concat(resultCode).concat(resultStatus).concat(checkoutUrl));
    }
    log.error("Testing ".concat(resultCode).concat(resultStatus).concat(checkoutUrl));
    }
```

**This is my input JSON**

```
{ 
   "response":{ 
      "head":{ 
         "function":"acquiring.order.create",
         "version":"2.0",
         "clientId":"201810300000",
         "reqMsgId":"56805892035",
         "respTime":"2019-09-13T13:18:08+08:00"
      },
      "body":{ 
         "resultInfo":{ 
            "resultCode":"SUCCESS",
            "resultCodeId":"00000000",
            "resultStatus":"S",
            "resultMsg":"SUCCESS"
         },
         "acquirementId":"2018080834569894848930",
         "merchantTransId":"5683668701112717398",
         "checkoutUrl":"http://localhost:8081/crm/operator/operator-search-init.action"
      }
   },
   "signature":"d+TUYLvtI38YL2hresd98Ixu1BXccvvh1IQMiHuMXUEeW/N5exUsW491R1e6aO8i9VwXWzVhfNgnhD0Du74f4RgBQ=="
}
```

Comment: version of `gson` is?

Comment: I am using gson-2.8.5 version  @michalk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the input from @Michalk: 
I understand that easy way to read JSON data is using Gson::fromJson and creating POJO class for out json.

I have generated POJO Classes supplying my sample input JSON using this [link](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) 
 and Now I have POJO Classes called : CreateOrderJSONResponse

```
Gson::fromJson
```

Sample :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
CreateOrderJSONResponse responseJson = gson.fromJson(inputJSON, CreateOrderJSONResponse.class);
```

Accessubg data :

```
    String resultCodeText =   responseJson.getResponse().getBody().getResultInfo().getResultCode();
    String resultCodeId =     responseJson.getResponse().getBody().getResultInfo().getResultCodeId();
    String resultStatus =     responseJson.getResponse().getBody().getResultInfo().getResultStatus();
    String checkoutUrl =      responseJson.getResponse().getBody().getCheckoutUrl();
```

Above `Gson::fromJson` example works smooth and it looks neat compare to direct accessing the filed  with below sample code :

```
 JsonObject jo = parser.parse(inputJSON).getAsJsonObject();

 String resultCodeText = jo.get("response").getAsJsonObject().get("body").getAsJsonObject().get("resultInfo").getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonPrimitive("resultCode").getAsString();
 String resultCodeId = jo.get("response").getAsJsonObject().get("body").getAsJsonObject().get("resultInfo").getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonPrimitive("resultCodeId").getAsString();
 String resultStatus = jo.get("response").getAsJsonObject().get("body").getAsJsonObject().get("resultInfo").getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonPrimitive("resultStatus").getAsString();
 String checkoutUrl = jo.get("response").getAsJsonObject().get("body").getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonPrimitive("checkoutUrl").getAsString();
```

Note : 
I have found this [link](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)  of JSON or JAVA, SCALA, POJO generator tools as **[GitHub](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo)** access you can access [here](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo)

Answer (score 6):

`JsonParser` parses your json into `JsonElement` structure. The behaviour that you see is a normal since you are using `toString` method of `JsonElement`. To achieve your goal just use `JsonElement::getAsString` method :

```
String resultCode = jo.get("response").getAsJsonObject().get("body").getAsJsonObject().get("resultInfo").getAsJsonObject().get("resultCode").getAsString();
```

which gives `SUCCESS` instead of `"SUCCESS"`

Note that `JsonElement` is an abstract class and classes, that extend this class, will override those helper `getAs...` methods. In your case [`JsonPrimitive::getAsString`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/JsonPrimitive.html#getAsString--) will be invoked.

Also you could create a POJO class for your json and use [`Gson::fromJson`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/Gson.html) to parse json into object of your POJO class.

Comment: but when i see API JsonElement::getAsString for 

public String getAsString() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

Comment: `JsonElement` is an abstract class and this method is overriden by subclasses. In your case it will be `JsonPrimitive::getAsString` that will be invoked.

Comment: Yes now i am getting value without """ 
I am new to JSON 
is this correct way to read the value :
--------------------------------------------

jo.get("response").getAsJsonObject().get("body").getAsJsonObject().get("resultInfo").getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonPrimitive("resultCode").getAsString();

from above code snippet

Comment: Yes it is correct. Both ways will work - yours and mine in the answer. I would also encourage you to look at `Gson::fromJson` and creating POJO class for your json. Then it would be easier for you to access the data from object of your POJO class.

Comment: I understood, your point Gson :: fromJson it really smooth and neat way to access data in the JSAON.  I will post the answer here.

Comment: Bloody hell, this has been driving me crazy for the last 2 days. ... thanks